# How i can parse or evaluate string with variables in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Well, i have a object like to:

```
$scope.variable = "mike";
$scope.country = "...";
$scope.posts = [
    ...
    {
        id:1,
        name: 'bla bla bla',
        content: 'Hello, my name is {{variable}} and i am from {{country}}'
    },
    ...
];
```

So, how i can evaluating or parse `content` property?

My idea is used it in my view like this:

```
<a ng-click=" variable = 'John' ">Change name here!</a>
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <h1>{{post.name}}</h1>
    <p>{{post.content}}</p>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: is your idea works, and you target is?

Comment: so basically you just want to concatenate the variable to the content property of posts?

Comment: I think either way, you're going to either have to pre-process the `posts` data before attaching it to the scope, or you'll have to transform it as it's rendered, i.e `<p>{{replaceVariables(post.content)}}</p>` - and then you would make a `$scope.replaceVariables = function(content){...};` that does the replacing, using any of the answers mentioned below. scope.$eval() might help out too.

Comment: Sometimes the information comes from databases or external agents. This information could be provided with "variable standards" are interpreted with AngularJS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a method in your controller that allows you to run the string through [`$interpolate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate), ie

```
// don't forget to inject the $interpolate service

$scope.parseContent = function(template) {
    return $interpolate(template)($scope);
};
```

Then you can use

```
<p>{{parseContent(post.content)}}</p>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/KB0aHsaoCxZGp3DY7JMI?p=preview

Comment: This work well, i think this is better option! thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
Assuming OP has access to `ES6`. Then try using the standard javascript API, `String template`.

**See:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

**Example:**

```js
"use strict";
let variable = "mike";
let country = "Australia";
let posts = [
    {
        id:1,
        name: 'bla bla bla',
        content: `Hello, my name is ${variable} and i am from ${country}`
    }
];

console.log(posts);
```

Note that the string begins and ends with a "`" character vs "

Also example in AngularJS:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SamuelToh/Lvc0u55v/8185/)

Comment: Thanks, but i need it on AngularJS, sorry

Comment: Isn't AngularJS javascript as well? Have you tried substituting with `${scope.country}`?

Comment: Try this ? content: 'Hello, my name is ' + $scope.variable + ' and i am from ' + $scope.country

Comment: The thing this answer is missing is that while console.log might properly apply the string interpolation (assuming OP is even using ES6), angularjs will not. So either OP would have to loop through all the data and re-set the content property manually before assigning it to his AngularJS scope, or he needs to do some angular magic - probably using $eval and $parse

Comment: @matmo Thanks for pointing out about the `ES6`. I have also updated the solution to include a JSFiddle example.

Comment: I like you example, but this don't work dynamically with `<a ng-click=" variable = 'John' ">Change name here!</a>` Thanks!!

Comment: I see. I probably will do a function call on `ng-click` and do the javascript stuff. Anyway that's fine. Possibility not an elegant solution for your case. Just chipping ideas :P